# Wizz discount club passenger name change

Tags: bookings, airlines, wizz-air

I am trying to change my passenger details on a Wizz flight, but its telling me that I can't make any changes since its a discounted ticket. I didn't see any where in the small print that it can't be changed,  Any advice??

Comment: This is a common restriction for airline tickets.  Are you trying to fix a typo, or give the ticket to someone else?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold for now.